# Is there software to make a video (Not flash) with a flash-like editor?

Tags: video, flash

I'm trying to make a simple time based video, where I can add animated characters to the video.  by animated I mean characters that will appear on the screen with little movement, tied to an audio track that is synced with the movie.

Is there a tool that is similar to Flash, but is built to create actual videos?

Comment: Why not just re-encode it?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of non-linear editing tools exist that can create animations from a few simple images. Try Sony Vegas, Adobe Premier, Avid, or Final Cut.